# xsd unique constraint not working

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a root Inserts tag, a sequence of Inserts tags, each with a "name" attribute.

I cannot get online validator to find out that there are duplicate "name" values.

We've been struggling for... days. Thanks for finding out.

XSD:

```
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.osames.org/osamesorm"
  targetNamespace="http://www.osames.org/osamesorm" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="Inserts">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Insert" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:complexType>
               <xs:simpleContent>
                  <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                  </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="unique-isbn">
          <xs:selector xpath="Inserts/Insert"/>
          <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
        </xs:unique>
      </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Inserts xmlns="http://www.osames.org/osamesorm"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osames.org/osamesorm ./xml_schemas/verysimple.xsd">
<Insert name="BaseInsert">INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) values ({2});</Insert>
<Insert name="BaseInsert">INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) values ({2});</Insert>
</Inserts>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two problems in your schema:

The first one is that your selector XPath is incorrect, based on the location where you define it. The `<xs:unique>` element is *within* an `<Inserts>` element, yet your XPath reads `Inserts/Insert`, meaning that within that `<Inserts>` element, another `<Inserts>` element is expected, and only therein an `<Insert>` element.

The `<xs:unique>` constraint is, however, already within the `<Inserts>` element, which is why you just need to find the `<Insert>` element:

```
<xs:unique name="unique-isbn">
  <xs:selector xpath="Insert"/>
  <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
</xs:unique>
```

The second issue is that XPath has no notion of the default namespace defined in Xml with the `xmlns` attribute. The `Insert` element you refer to in your XPath is *not* the `Insert` element from your XSD's default namespace, but an `Insert` element without a namespace URI.

To deal with that, add a namespace prefix for your namespace (as an alternative to the default namespace) to your XSD file:

```
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.osames.org/osamesorm" targetNamespace="http://www.osames.org/osamesorm" xmlns:o="http://www.osames.org/osamesorm" elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

Then, use that namespace prefix in your XPath:

```
<xs:unique name="unique-isbn">
  <xs:selector xpath="o:Insert"/>
  <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
</xs:unique>
```

With these changes, [this validator](http://www.xmlforasp.net/schemavalidator.aspx) outputs

> There is a duplicate key sequence 'BaseInsert' for the 'http://www.osames.org/osamesorm:unique-isbn' key or unique identity constraint. Line: 1 Column:357

Comment: I was having similar problem and key to solution is the use of namespace-prefix in selector!