# Error: S4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace Characters Are Not Allowed In Schema Elements Other Than 'xs:appinfo' And 'xs:documentation'

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have this xml-Schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
        <xs:element name="Fussballmannschaft">
                <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:attribute name="Stadt" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:attribute name="Tabellenplatz" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="Spieler">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:attribute name="SpielerID" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:keyref name="I_D" refer="Name" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element name="Torwart">
                                                <xs:attribute name="GehealteneElfmeter" type="xs:integer" />
                                                <xs:keyref name="ID_Torwart" refer="SpielerID" />
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="Verteidiger">
                                                <xs:attribute name="GewonneneZweikaempfe" type="xs:integer" />
                                                <xs:keyref name="ID_Verteidiger" refer="SpielerID" />
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="Stuermer">
                                                <xs:attribute name="GeschosseneTore" type="xs:integer" />
                                                <xs:keyref name="ID_Stuermer" refer="SpielerID" />
                                        </xs:element>
                                </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and this sample:

```
<Fussballmannschaft Name="BVB">
<Stadt>Dortmund</Stadt>
<Tabellenplatz>3</Tabellenplatz>
    <Spieler SpielerID="1">
        <I_D>BVB</I_D>
        <Name>Oliver</Name>
        <Torwart>
            <GehealteneElfmeter>20</GehealteneElfmeter>
            <ID_Torwart>1</ID_Torwart>
        </Torwart>
    </Spieler>

    <Spieler SpielerID="2">
        <I_D>BVB</I_D>
        <Name>Peter</Name>
        <Torwart>
            <GewonneneZweikaempfe>20</GewonneneZweikaempfe>
            <ID_Verteidiger>2</ID_Verteidiger>
        </Torwart>
    </Spieler>

    <Spieler SpielerID="3">
        <I_D>BVB</I_D>
        <Name>Paul</Name>
        <Torwart>
            <GeschosseneTore>20</GeschosseneTore>
            <ID_Stuermer>3</ID_Stuermer>
        </Torwart>
    </Spieler>
</Fussballmannschaft>
```

But the parser says:

> S4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace Characters Are Not Allowed In Schema Elements Other Than 'xs:appinfo' And 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Dortmund'.

Do you know where the problem is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Stadt` and `Tabellenplatz` mustn't be xml elements but need to be attributes of the element `Fussballmannschaft`. This pattern repeats with the inner elements.

The schema also lacks structures to express repetition of elements (namely the `Spieler` element) and choices between player roles (`Torwart`,`Verteidiger`,`Stuermer`).

The use of the `xs:keyref` in the schema definition appears to be incomplete - the referenced keys are not specified as `xs:key` elements. In order to demonstrate this use, a new root element `Fussball` is defined, which should reflect the intent of the schema to formalize the notion of soccer teams. This new root element harbors the key and keyref definitions for the club name attribute and will be needed anyway as soon as multiple teams are to be represented in in a file (there must be a single root element in an xml file ).

The following pair of schema and sample passes the validation.

Schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Fussball">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Fussballmannschaft">
                    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Spieler" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                                    <xs:choice>
                                        <xs:element name="Torwart">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:attribute name="GehalteneElfmeter" type="xs:integer" />
                                                <xs:attribute name="ID_Torwart" type="xs:integer" />
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="Verteidiger">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:attribute name="GewonneneZweikaempfe" type="xs:integer" />
                                                <xs:attribute name="ID_Verteidiger" type="xs:integer" />
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                        <xs:element name="Stuermer">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:attribute name="GeschosseneTore" type="xs:integer" />
                                                <xs:attribute name="ID_Stuermer" type="xs:integer"/>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:choice>
                                    <xs:attribute name="I_D" type="xs:string" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="SpielerID" type="xs:integer" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="Spielername" type="xs:string" />
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element><!-- Spieler -->
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:attribute name="Stadt" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:attribute name="Tabellenplatz" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:complexType>

                    <xs:key name="k-Spieler">
                        <xs:selector xpath="./Spieler"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@SpielerID"/>
                    </xs:key>
                    <xs:keyref name="kref-Spieler" refer="k-Spieler">
                        <xs:selector xpath="./Spieler/Stuermer|./Spieler/Torwart|./Spieler/Verteidiger"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@ID_Stuermer|@ID_Torwart|@ID_Verteidiger"/>
                    </xs:keyref>
                </xs:element><!-- Fussballmannschaft -->
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <!--
            A 'key' tells you how to uniquely reference an element instance - eg. one among several soccer teams. 
        -->
        <xs:key name="k-Verein">
            <xs:selector xpath="./Fussballmannschaft"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@Name"/>
        </xs:key>

        <!--
            A 'keyref' specifies that some attribute value(s) are not only constrained by their datatype but must also uniquely identify a certain element in the file - a semantic relationship is established.
        -->
        <xs:keyref name="kref-Verein" refer="k-Verein">
            <xs:selector xpath="./Fussballmannschaft/Spieler"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@I_D"/>
        </xs:keyref>
    </xs:element><!-- Fussball -->
</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
<Fussball>
    <Fussballmannschaft Name="BVB" Stadt="Dortmund" Tabellenplatz="3">
        <Spieler SpielerID="1" I_D="BVB" Spielername="Oliver">
            <Torwart GehalteneElfmeter="20" ID_Torwart="1"/>
        </Spieler>
        <Spieler SpielerID="2" I_D="BVB" Spielername="Peter">
            <Verteidiger GewonneneZweikaempfe="20" ID_Verteidiger="2"/>
        </Spieler>
        <Spieler SpielerID="3" I_D="BVB" Spielername="Paul">
            <Stuermer GeschosseneTore="20" ID_Stuermer="3"/>
        </Spieler>
    </Fussballmannschaft>
</Fussball>
```

**References**

- [W3C XML Schema Definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/)
- [W3C XML Schema Definition / identity constraints](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#Identity-constraint_Definition_details)
- [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662664/how-to-use-unique-and-keyref-properly-in-xml-schema) on the use of `key` and `keyref`

Comment: Thanks, but I still get this error: "S4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace Characters Are Not Allowed In Schema Elements Other Than 'xs:appinfo' And 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'BVB'.", when I validate on https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html

Comment: @Marc Yes, you have a similar issue with the `Spieler` element and its children. The latter must be attributes as well.

Comment: +1 for all the great XSD help, but the real reason for the error in OP's question is that he's attempting to [**validate the XML file itself as if it were an XSD**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51219191/290085).

Answer (score 12):

The real reason you're getting this error,

> S4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace Characters Are Not Allowed In Schema Elements Other Than 'xs:appinfo' And 'xs:documentation

is that you're **attempting to validate your XML file as an XSD file**.

So, fix the way you're invoking your validating parser so that you're validating your ***XML*** file against your XSD.  See *[How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)*

Additionally, there are a slew of other problems with your XSD itself.  See [collapsar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51218537/290085) for help there.

Answer (score 9):

We also had this problem. The reason was the address of the schema http:://xyz.xsd was replaced with https:://xyz.xsd. Our schema library was not able to forward to the https address via http one. So we simply changed the http adresses to https ones in the xml file.