# XML Validation for config file

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am trying to get an XML Schema for a config file type XML working.

Here's what I have got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com" 
    xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="config" type="config">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="module" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="parameter" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                    <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Example file that should be legal:

```
<config>
    <module name="module1">
        <parameter name="param1" value="1.234" type="float"/>
    </module>
    <module name="module2">
        <parameter name="param1" value="Hello there!" type="string"/>
        <parameter name="param2" value="3.1415" type="float"/>
    </module>
</config>
```

But I get the error `Cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element config`. What did I do wrong here? I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51218537/6301103) and at least to me it seems I correctly adopted it for my purpose but somehow my root object config isn't defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your XML Schema, since `xs:element` cannot have both a `name` and `type` attribute.

After fixing this: because of how you defined namespaces in your XML Schema, a document that is valid would need to be in the namespace `https://www.w3schools.com`. The solution is to a) either fix your XML document to include this namespace (see above), or b) change your XSD to not expect a namespace.

**Fixing the XML document (no change to the XML Schema)**

This would be a valid document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com">
    <module name="module1">
        <parameter name="param1" value="1.234" type="float"/>
    </module>
    <module name="module2">
        <parameter name="param1" value="Hello there!" type="string"/>
        <parameter name="param2" value="3.1415" type="float"/>
    </module>
</config>
```

**XML Schema that does not expect a namespace (no change to the XML document)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:element name="config">
        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="module" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="parameter" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                    <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

**Other improvements to your XML Schema**

Your schema is a bit hard to read, because of the heavy nesting. Here is an alternative version that defines named complex types. Also, your types are "mixed", whereas, looking at your XML document, I do not think they should be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:element name="config" type="configType" />

    <xs:complexType name="configType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="module" type="moduleType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="moduleType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="parameter" type="parameterType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="parameterType">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

---

**Edit: introducing a different custom namespace**

**XML Document**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns="https://www.myowndomain.com">
    <module name="module1">
        <parameter name="param1" value="1.234" type="float"/>
    </module>
    <module name="module2">
        <parameter name="param1" value="Hello there!" type="string"/>
        <parameter name="param2" value="3.1415" type="float"/>
    </module>
</config>
```

**XML Schema**

In the schema, you would remove all references to `w3schools.com` and replace with your own namespace URI.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="https://www.myowndomain.com" xmlns="https://www.myowndomain.com">

    <xs:element name="config" type="configType" />

    <xs:complexType name="configType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="module" type="moduleType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="moduleType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="parameter" type="parameterType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="parameterType">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. However when I try to take your nicely cleaned up schema and try to [validate](https://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0) it, I am getting the same errors. Am I using a bad validator maybe?

Also how can I fix the namespaces for `mydomain.com`? Don't I need to have the definitons of the w3.org to be able to use the schema?

Comment: okay, I have tried a handful of xml+xsd validators now and none even pass tutorial code snippets form w3. Any recommendations for a sensible validator?

Comment: @jaaq An example for a command-line tool: xmllint, for an XML IDE: Oxygen.

Comment: @jaaq "Also how can I fix the namespaces for mydomain.com? Don't I need to have the definitons of the w3.org to be able to use the schema?" - Sorry, I don't understand what "fixing namespaces" means in this context, and what "definitions of w3.org" means.

Comment: I think the confusion is on my side. Basically, how do I correctly replace the w3schools namespace with e.g. `myowndomain.com`; and should I even do that?

Comment: @jaaq So, you would like your document to be in the namespace `myowndomain.com`?

Comment: Thank you very much! That should cover all of it, and if not that'd probably warrant its own question.